# How create a tracklist on Omxplayer

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, omxplayer

I'm doing some development with python / [omxplayer-wrapper](https://python-omxplayer-wrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/omxplayer/) / omxplayer and I realized that even though there is a interface to check if there is a track list and to skip to the previous / next track, there is no docs on how to generate a track list.

How can I create a track list ? I'm using a compiled version from the latest release from [popcornmix/omxplayer](https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer).

Comment: What do you mean by "tracklist"? Do you mean something like "playlist"? Are you looking for a list of tracks appearing in a particular given order?

Comment: @M.Rostami yes, exactly

Comment: I suggest you search "create playlist Omxplayer" instead of "create tracklist Omxplayer". It will give you some amazing results. However, did you check these links? [(1)](https://keytosmart.com/single-board-computers/looping-video-playlist-omxplayer-raspberry-pi/) - [(2)](https://gist.github.com/akirasy/ca2a5bd67f16b17dd896eed30139ad29) - [(3)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=219989)

Comment: @M.Rostami yes. All of those use external tools to control the playlist, starting a new process to play the next file. my intention in this question is to find how to do that in a single process.

Comment: Alright. Please add this important information to the question and explain what is the exact problem with them. It may help others. Although, I don't understand what you mean by "single process".

Comment: I assume you want all control and playlist in a single python file? Creater made OMX run a single file only. So you need to build a console around it yourself to do track skipping, forward/reversing, etc. See comments [here](https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer/issues/370) on github. So basically what you ask is "write me a GUI with all functions I need". As SO is not a coding on command you need to show effort in building it yourself and tell us what goes wrong. The +50 rep won't cut it for the amount of work this needs.

Comment: @ZF007 no, I'm not asking for a code. And, considering wht you said, whats the point of the `HasTrackList` / `CanGoNext` function on the dbus control? This is what drawn my interest. I should have been clearer about this function on the question D:

Comment: ... just bounty surfing... no experience with OMXplayer. My suggestion... update your question accordingly instead of keeping it as is and lack attention of the right persons on your quest...

Comment: Consider these 2 links if they will be of any help at all
1. https://gist.github.com/akirasy/ca2a5bd67f16b17dd896eed30139ad29
2. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=219989

Comment: I think there is some confusion here about what track list means. My understanding is that most audio files have different tracks (for stereo, or even to separate instruments like drums, voice, etc.). This is totally different from a playlist which is a collection of files. I believe OMX player let you switch to one track or another in the same file but doesn't handle playlists.